# FullCalendar: remove events on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to remove a dynamically selected event from FullCalendar.

[image]

when this event is rendered it will be also displayed in the table with a delete button at the end of every row.
[image]

what i want to do is when I click the delete button, it will also delete the event on the calendar.
I can remove the row from the table but not in the calendar.

here is my code for selecting the event

```
var eventID = 0;
$('.calendar').fullCalendar({
    select: function(start, end, event, view, resource) {
            if(start.isBefore(moment())) {
                $('.calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                swal('Ooops!','You cannot select past date/time!','error')
            }else{
                $('#reserved_date').val(moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
                $('#end_time').val(moment(end).format("hh:mm A"));
                $('#start_time').val(moment(start).format("hh:mm A"));
                $('#newScheduleModal').modal({
                    show : true,
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false
                });
                eventData = {
                    id: eventID +1,
                    title: 'Lesson Schedule',
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                };
            }
            $(".fc-highlight").css("background", "red");

    },
    events: obj,
    eventRender:function( ev, element ) { 
        eventID++; 
        $('#sched_data').append('<tr class="tb-row">'+
            '<td>'+moment(ev.start).format('MMM. DD, YYYY')+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+moment(ev.start).format('hh:mm A')+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+moment(ev.end).format('hh:mm A')+'</td>'+
            '<td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-del btn-xs" data-id"'+ev._id+'"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td></tr>'
        )
    },

})
```

here's the code for rendering the event to calendar

```
$('#btn-reserve').click(function(){
        $('.calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);

})
```

and here's my code for deleting an event

```
  $('body').on('click','.btn-del',function(){
    $(this).closest('.tb-row').remove();
    $('.calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', $(this).data('id'));
  })
```

Comment: What's your problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already did it,

My code:

```
$('body').on('click','.btn-del',function(){
    $(this).closest('.tb-row').remove();
    $('.calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', $(this).data('id'));
})
```

What it should be

```
$('body').on('click','.btn-del',function(){
    var del_btn = $(this);
    del_btn.closest('.tb-row').remove();

    $(".calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents', function(event) {
        return event.id == del_btn.data('id');
    });
})
```

the second parameter should be a function and not just the plain id.

Answer (score 1):

If you to delete an event with the `eventClick` you can try like this :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, /*OPTIONS*/);

  calendar.on('eventClick', function (info) {
    calendar.getEventById(info.event.id).remove();
  });

});
```

Comment: when you create an event, don't forget to add an ID, like this :

{
            id: ID,
            title: TITLE,
            ......
}

Answer (score 0):

Every event in Fullcalendar has its own ID generated by Fullcalender.

plz add this to your arguments:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#calender').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);
},
```